# How can I give alternative names to new objects created by LINQ?

Tags: linq

How can I give specific names to the customers variable's properties, e.g.:

*PSEUDO-CODE:*

```
var customers = from c in Customers
    where c.Orders.Count > 15
    orderby c.Orders.Count ascending
    select new { 
        c.ContactName as Name, 
        c.City, 
        c.Orders.Count as NumberOfOrders };
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like this, using the [object initializer syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
var customers = from c in Customers
    where c.Orders.Count > 15
    orderby c.Orders.Count ascending
    select new 
    { 
        Name = c.ContactName, 
        c.City, 
        NumberOfOrders = c.Orders.Count
    };
```

Comment: @CMS you think this is all he wants? +1 for answering exactly what he asked.